# Chance that one random outcome beats another one?

Tags: combinatorics

After some studies I´m able to calculate combinations and permutations, but I fail to compare multiple events. Imagine you have 2 groups of fair conis: one group with 3 coins, the other one with 4. What´s the chance that the 4-coin group shows more heads than the 3-coin-group?
I´ve tried drawing a matrix with every possible outcome, (and fiddled with pascals triangle) but there must be some calculatory way.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly toss $3$ coins each, then by symmetry,
each group will have equal probability of having more heads = $p,\;$say, then P(tie) $= 1-2p$

With one more toss, the $4$ coin group is sure to win if leading, and win with $Pr = \frac12$ if tied,

thus P($4$ coin group wins) $= p +\frac12(1-2p) = \frac12$

Answer (score 1):

Split it into disjoint events, and then add up their probabilities:

$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{4}\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{\binom4n\cdot\binom3k}{2^4\cdot2^3}=\frac12$$